# The code bundled with deno causes an error in the browser

Tags: typescript, webassembly, deno

The code bundled with deno causes an error in the browser.

Sample code

```rust
const rust = import('../pkg/wasm_deno.js');
rust
  .then(m => m.greet('World!'));
```

```rust
//@deno-types="../pkg/wasm_deno.d.ts"
import { greet } from '../pkg/wasm_deno.js';
greet('Hello');
```

```rust
import init, { greet } from '../pkg/wasm_deno.js';
async function run() {
  await init();
  greet('hello');
}
run();
```

Build command

```
$ cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release
$ wasm-bindgen target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/wasm_deno.wasm --out-dir ./server/public/pkg --target deno
$ deno bundle server/public/ts/greet.ts server/public/js/greet.js
```

Get errors such as "Fetch API cannot load" or "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property'__wbindgen_malloc' of undefined".

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by reading the wasm file separately using fetch.

```js
import init, { greet } from '../pkg/wasm_deno.js';
async function run() {
  await init(await fetch('../public/pkg/wasm_deno_bg.wasm'));
  greet('hello');
}
run();
```